# Neo4j LOAD CSV not working when I use link from github

Tags: neo4j, load-csv

I have this piece of code which loads a csv from another site.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://www.quackit.com/neo4j/tutorial/genres.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Genre { GenreId: line[0], Name: line[1]})
```

[image]

But when I upload the same csv to my github account and try it, it gives me an error.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://www.quackit.com/neo4j/tutorial/genres.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Genre { GenreId: line[0], Name: line[1]})[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

[image]
I only changed the link and nothing else. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the RAW version of the file.

On your github repo, click on your genres.csv file and then click on RAW

[image]

Then copy the url and use it in your LOAD CSV command :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JP-Reddy/Recommendation-Engine/master/genres.csv

Comment: Also how do import from my pc? 'file:C/path/destination/file.csv' isn't working. I'm using windows

Comment: you need to put it in the import directory of the neo4j db or allow (via the neo4j config) to traverse the filesystem. Check the neo4j documentation ;-)